# All element in group are the same $ord(g) = p$.

Tags: group-theory

Consider the group $G$ with $\forall (g\ne e) \in G$ we have $ord(g) = p$, , then $p$ is prime.

My attempt : I consider some element $a_{1}$, if $ord(a_{1}) = p$ then $ord(a_{1}^{k}) = p$. So if we show that all element are the type of $a^{m}$,then we prove that there is only one subgroup and therefore $|G| = p$. I also tried suppose that there are some subgroups $<a_{1}> \dots <a_{k}>$.

Comment: Are you claiming that all groups of order $p^2$ are cyclic?  (as a non-cyclic group of order $p^2$ would have the property you require.)

Answer (score 3):

If $|g|=p=ab$ where $a,b>1$, then $|g^a|=b \ne p$.

Comment: More generally, $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^n$ with $n>1$ (possibly even infinite)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $n=\mathfrak c$ :P

Comment: And of course there are nonabelian examples when $p>2$, and Tarski Monsters for large enough $p$.

Comment: Edited , my bad..

Comment: @openspace "if $p$ is prime, then $p$ is prime"?

Comment: @KennyLau edited

Comment: @openspace edited